# mailgun shows 500 error when trying to forward emails containing attachment on webpage

Tags: email, mailgun

i am trying to forward all the incoming emails on my domain to a webpage.I am using mailgun api for this. Its working fine for the emails which doesn't have any attachments but it shows an internal 500 server error for the emails having attachments.